# PHP MVC Best practices - model for every controller?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

In terms of a best practice, when working with MVC frameworks, is it fair to say that every controller should have an associated model? and only one model?

Or, should it be more decoupled, where as you create models for specific purposes and they can be used anywhere within the app?

Thanks! Just interested in any suggestions

Comment: Where did you get the idea of "one (and only one) model per controller"? Never heard of that one.

Comment: I don't have separate models per controller, per se.  What I do is I have models for each purpose, like `contacts`, `articles`, `comments`.  I use the models where they are needed, in whatever controller.

Comment: they're models, not complements... One controller --- all the models it needs to elaborate its data --- all the views it needs to display those data.

Comment: What kind of controllers are you using? What is the general design of your application? Are you referring to some standard layer models with your application or are you just throwing the term "MVC" in and you can't specify further?

Comment: The question is rather general and should probably be part of programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I found this question pretty much the same as what I was wondering - according to best practice, does every controller have a corresponding model? If so, creating the model can be done in the base controller extended by your current controller. If not, then the base controller won't have this automatic creation of the corresponding model in it's construct. If not according to a SPECIFIC MVC framework, what are the best practice guidelines associated with this question? Maybe not the best worded question, but still valid in my opinion. Therefore, I am +1ing this question, even a year later.

Answer (score 3):

If the framework follows a pattern that associates one model per controller, then it is fair to say that every controller should have one associated model (and only one model).

However, you have not written if you're using such a type of MVC framework or not, so, to come back to general MVC frameworks: No, it's not fair to say. It would be fair to say: Do whatever you want, use whatever and how many models you want to if the framework you use allows you to.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common misconception... You should have one model per lot of information to work with. Not one per table. You should "normally" have one controller per model because you usually manage this information in units, but nothing prevents you to have a controller for "shoppingbasket" and not have a specific model for it...

Models = code representation of data that you have in your database

Controllers = general navigation logic representing ACTIONS that your users can do...

Comment: Models can be more than Database Models. And Controllers must not represent actions. So +1 for common misconception but -1 for doing it as well.

Comment: Most people work only with database but you are right about models being more than database data. It can be xml file(s) or a complex arrangement of several data sources. Regarding the controllers, i meant to say that it is an arrangement of actions that the user can do and the controller is in charge of making sure the flow is ok. A bit like a Business Logic controller, but for action flow, not for data.

Comment: Models (some): [Presentation Model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html), [Domain Model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html); Controllers (some): [Page Controller](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/pageController.html), [Front Controller](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/frontController.html), [Supervising Controller](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/SupervisingPresenter.html). Your examples are misleading about models again, you would use files and XML as a database, so you actually still talk about db models, but models are much more than db abstraction.